# Sencha build failed compass process exited with non-zero code 1

Tags: sencha-touch-2, compass-sass, sencha-cmd

I am trying to build my Sencha app at windows OS but getting this error.
I am trying to use sencha command - sencha app build package, but build is failed.
I already installed ant and compass

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\WhatsUnderMe>sencha app build package
Sencha Cmd v3.1.0.256
[INF]
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF]
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF] Invoking plugin (C:\xampp\htdocs\WhatsUnderMe\.sencha\app\plugin.xml) - supported targets: -before-app-build
[INF]
[INF] -before-app-build:
[INF] Invoking plugin (C:\xampp\htdocs\WhatsUnderMe\.sencha\app\plugin.xml) - supported targets: app-build
[INF]
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-sencha-command:
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] -before-app-build:
[INF]
[INF] app-build-impl:
[INF]
[INF] package:
[INF]
[INF] -before-init-local:
[INF]
[INF] -init-local:
[INF]
[INF] -after-init-local:
[INF]
[INF] init-local:
[INF]
[INF] find-cmd:
[INF]
[INF] -before-init:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF] Initializing Sencha Cmd ant environment
[INF] Adding antlib taskdef for com/sencha/command/compass/ant/antlib.xml
[INF]
[INF] -after-init:
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] -before-build:
[INF]
[INF] sass:
[INF]
[INF] -before-sass:
[INF]
[INF] -sass:
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
NoMethodError on line ["23"] of C: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/sass-3.1.7/lib/sass/engine.rb:293:in `_render'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/sass-3.1.7/lib/sass/engine.rb:240:in `render'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:140:in `block (2 leve
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:139:in `block in comp
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/logger.rb:45:in `red'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:138:in `compile'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:118:in `compile_if_re
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:103:in `block (2 leve
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `each'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:101:in `block in run'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:126:in `timed'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/compiler.rb:100:in `run'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:45:in
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `e
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `per
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `call'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/bin/compass:23:in `load'
  C:/Users/Ido Tsuk/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.0.256/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code : 1
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 0 seconds
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR] C:\xampp\htdocs\WhatsUnderMe\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:223: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 1 second
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\xampp\htdocs\WhatsUnderMe\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:223: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code : 1
```

What can i do to solve it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same error with Sencha Touch 2.2,Sencha Cmd 3.1.1.270 and Ruby 2.x.

To fix this I uninstalled Ruby 2.x and installed Ruby 1.9.3
http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/76798/rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p392.exe

Hope this is helpful for you. Otherwise you should provide more details about the versions you're using. Or you can start using the latest versions like me.

Comment: Quick question. Just curious - what if:
- I installed Ruby 2.x.
- Then installed compass.
- Then uninstalled Ruby 2.x.
- And installed back Ruby 1.9.3.
Q: Will I need to install compass again? Meaning, when we uninstall Ruby in Windows, does it remove all installed packages with it too?

Comment: I don´t believe! You're right. It works.
Does anyone know a way to view in a simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Installing 1.9.3 ruby works for most people. For me it didnt work.

What i did to fix it was creating a new project and copying the touch folder and resources to my current project. After that i could build normally.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use both version of Ruby simultaneously due to many annoying reasons. Therefore, I hope, that next advise will be helpful for all guys (and girls) who can't remove newer version of Ruby:

- You need to install *ruby-switch*: `sudo apt-get install ruby-switch`.
- Then check current version: `ruby -v`.
- Show list of available versions: `ruby-switch --list`.
- Set older (newer) version as default for now: `sudo ruby-switch --set ruby2.2`.
- Check current version: `ruby -v`